# blocking 'connect' system call is interrupted

Tags: sockets, unix

I am reading Unix Network Programming by W. Richard Stevens.
The author says if a blocking connect call is interrupted, I could use 'select' as for select for the nonblocking connect.

I am confused. If I should call a non blocking connect and then select on the new socktfd, or just should select on the old socketfd which is passed to the previous blocking connect call ?

And I see in a post, say 'connect' is restartable if signal action is passed with SA_RESTART flag. If so could I totally ignore the blocking connect interrupted case ?

Comment: Type `man 7 signal` at the prompt.  Search for EINTR.  It explains it all.  If you don't have any code in your process that could trigger a signal, then you may not have to worry about this. Or you could treat EINTR as a transient error (similar to EAGAIN, EWOULDBLOCK) and just recover gracefully.

Comment: What 'new sockfd'?  You only have one per socket. Calling connect() doesn't create a new Le.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using blocking call you will have to check the error code and retry based on error code which will be EINTR in case of interruption. Otherwise use select which doesnt return because of interuption. Select only returns in case of timeout, error or read write signal.

Comment: yup sorry my mistake. fixed it.

Comment: The thing I'm trying to figure out is this. If an application doesn't invoke signals within its own code, can EINTR actually happen? Or are there some common libraries that do that generate these signal interrupts that would interfere with the socket code?

Comment: I think it can, since signal can be sent interprocess, i.e. kill -9 .

Comment: @AdnanAkbar I wonder what should I do with the the socked and select when connect() is interrupted. for example, the code maybe like: int fd; fd = socket(); connect(fd); /* then interrupted */ what should the code be like if I prefer to use select */ ?

Comment: You need to check errno and in case of EINTR call connect again.